# Express POST request from React return empty body

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

> Hello, I am working on a react/express app. I've been able to make a GET request from my server, however, I'm having trouble making a POST request. When I do, my server is returning an empty body. I have body-parser as a dependency, accepting json as content, but still no luck with the empty body. My code and dependencies for server/client are below. Please let me know if you guys see something I don't.

Index.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const path = require('path');
 const app = express();
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//routes
 require('./routes/sendMessageToEmail')(app);
 require('./routes/helloWorld')(app);

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 1111;
app.listen(port);
```

> When I switch the order around of where my routes are declared in my index.js file, for example, declare the routes line after

```
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

> Line, I get an undefined as oppose to an empty body.

POST Route

```
   module.exports = app => {
     app.post('/api/message', (req, res) => {
      console.log('>>>>>>>>>> ', req.body);
      res.send(req.body)
     });
    }
```

> My console.log is returning an empty object. I've made the post request in postman, from my browser, curl etc. I'm getting a 200 status response back, however, the body is still empty.

Server package.json

```
{
  "name": "Blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3"
  }
}
```

Client Package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-iframe": "^1.0.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.5.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.71.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:1111/"
}
```

React POST Route

```
import axios from 'axios';

const sendToExpress = (input) => {
 return fetch('/api/message', {
   mode: 'no-cors',
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
   Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({message: 'asdfafa;k'})
   //body: JSON.stringify({"message": input})
  })
}


//ACTION CREATORS

export const sendInputToServer = (input) => ({
 type: 'SEND_INPUT_TO_SERVER', payload: sendToExpress(input)
});
```

> Any help is appreciated here figuring out why my post request is returning an empty body.

Comment: your routes definitely need to go after the body parser middleware.  Also, in your route, you probably also want to use res.json() instead of result.send since your client is expecting to receive json

Comment: Hey, I switched the routes around and tried res.json() as well, but still no cigar. Anything else you can see in my code that might be an issue with the post body returning empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

`mode: 'no-cors'`

Worked for me.